# split a string based on some parameter in python

Tags: python, string

```
  var1 = "0123456789"
```

I need to store this string into another string variables by breaking it into 3 parts like

```
  par1 = '0123'
  par2 = '4567'
  par3 ='89
```

Purpose: 
I have got a dataset I need to break the each record and store it in different variables.

Comment: What are parameters here?

Comment: So what's your parameters?

Comment: You can pass any iterable object (including string) to the functions mentioned in the duped question

Comment: Perhaps you want chunking.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you have constant 'slices' to do, for your example you can do:

```
par1 = var1[:4]
par2 = var1[4:8]
par3 = var1[8:]
```

play with this method, it works pretty well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of each part, you can use string slicing and unpacking feature of python:

```
var1 = "0123456789"

par1, par2, par3 = var1[:4], var1[4:8], var1[8:]


>>> var1
'0123456789'
>>> par1
'0123'
>>> par2
'4567'
>>> par3
'89'
>>>
```